# Multiple relatedTo conditions using a combination of "and" and "or"

Tags: query, relatedto, nested

We're trying to make a filter that allows you to pick multiple items from 1 category, and multiple items from another category and return back all appropriate elements.

We're in PHP land not twig so the starting point we have is...

```
$results = Entry::find()
    ->type('recipe')
    ->relatedTo($conditions)
    ->all();
```

The pseudo query would be...

```
SELECT * FROM `entries`
WHERE
 (`food_type` = "cake" or `category` = "burger")
AND
(`weather` = "summer" or `tag` is "hot")
```

I've got the IDs and the hydrated models/elements of each category but can't figure out how to nest the conditions using the `relatedTo` method on the query..

Thanks

Comment: Here's how to do it in Twig: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/36309/271 - You can probably take that logic and convert it fairly easily into PHP.

Comment: Hmmm I'd seen similar ones but the `and` is confusing as it never states `or` anywhere, I guess this is maybe then implied... thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `relatedTo` is by default an `or`, so you only need to define `and` once when the rest will be considered `or` e.g.

```
$query = Entry::find();

// Convert these IDs into Entries/Category models first.
$foodTypes = [1, 3, 5];
$weathers = [7, 4];

$query->relateTo([
    'and',
    ['targetElement' => $foodTypes],
    ['targetElement' => $weathers],
]);

return $query->all();
```

This will make sure each array passed into `relateTo` is considered an `and group` but the items within that are considered as an `or group`.